# more_rewrite does not do the same on different machines

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have two machines (DEV/PROD) with two different apache versions but same configuration.

DEV:  Apache/2.4.18
PROD: Apache/2.4.33

This is my virtualhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:14000>
  ServerName xxxx.com

  ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/www.xxxx.com_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.xxxx.com_access.log vhost_combined env=!nolog

  SetEnv ENVIRONMENT "PROD"
  SetEnv SITE "XXXX"
  SetEnv SITE_ID "7"

  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule "^/es/XXXX/(.*)$"  "/$1" [N]

    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sitecode/XXXX/static%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" -f
    RewriteRule "^(.+)" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sitecode/XXXX/static$1"  [L]

    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sitecode/XXXX/dynamic%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" -f
    RewriteRule "^(.+)" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sitecode/XXXX/dynamic$1"  [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(js|txt|html|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf|zip|css|ico|svg)$
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>

  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/site
  <Directory /var/www/vhosts/site>
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything works great on DEV, but not on PROD.

Sample request

```
% curl https://xxxx.com/es/BASE/js/common.js
```

on DEV works without any problem, mod_rewrite removes "**/es/BASE**" from the path and look for the static file on the right dir "**/var/www/vhosts/site/sitecode/XXXX/static/js/common.js**"

but in PROD same rules try to find the file in "**/var/www/vhosts/site/sitecode/XXXX/static/es/BASE/js/common.js**"
Note that "**/es/BASE**" was not removed.

Here it goes the logs from DEV

```
[rid#7f30501030a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /es/BASE/js/common.js
[rid#7f30501030a0/initial] applying pattern '^/es/BASE/(.*)$' to uri '/es/BASE/js/common.js'
[rid#7f30501030a0/initial] rewrite '/es/BASE/js/common.js' -> '/js/common.js'
[rid#7f30501030a0/initial] applying pattern '^/es/BASE/(.*)$' to uri '/js/common.js'
[rid#7f30501030a0/initial] applying pattern '^(.+)' to uri '/js/common.js'
[rid#7f30501030a0/initial] rewrite '/js/common.js' -> '/var/www/vhosts/site/sitecode/XXXX/static/js/common.js'
[rid#7f30501030a0/initial] local path result: /var/www/vhosts/site/sitecode/XXXX/static/js/common.js
[rid#7f30501030a0/initial] go-ahead with /var/www/vhosts/site/sitecode/XXXX/static/js/common.js [OK]
```

and this is logs from PROD

```
[rid#559c3a1c18f0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /es/BASE/js/common.js
[rid#559c3a1c18f0/initial] applying pattern '^/es/BASE/(.*)$' to uri '/es/BASE/js/common.js'
[rid#559c3a1c18f0/initial] rewrite '/es/BASE/js/common.js' -> '/js/common.js'
[rid#559c3a1c18f0/initial] applying pattern '^/es/BASE/(.*)$' to uri '/js/common.js'
[rid#559c3a1c18f0/initial] applying pattern '^' to uri '/js/common.js'
[rid#559c3a1c18f0/initial] RewriteCond: input='https' pattern='!https' [NC] => not-matched
[rid#559c3a1c18f0/initial] applying pattern '^(.+)' to uri '/js/common.js'
[rid#559c3a1c18f0/initial] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/vhosts/site/sitecode/XXXX/static/es/BASE/js/common.js' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[rid#559c3a1c18f0/initial] applying pattern '^(.+)' to uri '/js/common.js'
[rid#559c3a1c18f0/initial] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/vhosts/site/sitecode/XXXX/dynamic/es/BASE/js/common.js' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[rid#559c3a1c18f0/initial] applying pattern '.' to uri '/js/common.js'
[rid#559c3a1c18f0/initial] RewriteCond: input='/js/common.js' pattern='!\\.(js|txt|html|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf|zip|css|ico|svg)$' => not-matched
[rid#559c3a1c18f0/initial] local path result: /js/common.js
[rid#559c3a1c18f0/initial] prefixed with document_root to /var/www/vhosts/site/js/common.js
[rid#559c3a1c18f0/initial] go-ahead with /var/www/vhosts/site/js/common.js [OK]
```

Any idea about what's wrong?

xabi

Comment: Judging by `RewriteCond: input='https' pattern='!https' [NC] => not-matched`, there must be a part of configuration not shown here...